# What's a word for someone who needs to always be flustered about something?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

A word for a person who if left in an impossibly perfect environment, would find a way to be upset with how perfect it was.

Someone who will invent issues to be offended about. Someone who is never satisfied.

I found a similar post here but it's not quite the same: [A word for a person who always needs there to be a problem?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327451/a-word-for-a-person-who-always-needs-there-to-be-a-problem)

I'm not talking about someone who holds onto problems after they're fixed, but someone who must always have a problem at all times, no matter how small.

Drama Queen is close, but not quite right.

Entitled is very close.

Comment: I fail to see how the post you reference is not a duplicate. The distinction you're trying to make doesn't convince me it's not the same. Also "someone who is never satisfied" is [**insatiable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insatiable).

Comment: I don't think the word "flustered" applies at all to the sort of person you're describing. (Not to say that such a person couldn't also be flustered.)

Comment: I believe this _is_ a duplicate of your question: [A word for a person who always needs there to be a problem?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327451/a-word-for-a-person-who-always-needs-there-to-be-a-problem)

Comment: It's similar. But in that example they wouldn't accept a solution. The sort of person I'm thinking of will accept a solution but will invent a new problem afterwards. Both of the answers here are pretty good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near-synonyms are plenty, but *"captious"* is the word you are looking for.
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/captious

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

How about-

**glass-half-empty person**

used to refer to an attitude of always thinking about the bad things in a situation rather than the good ones:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glass-is-half-empty